# Time complexity of recursive functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to derive the number of times * is performed in the following function.

```
int f(n) {

    if (n == 1)

         return 2*3;

    else

         return f(n-2)*f(n-2)*f(n-2);

}
```

Can someone help me in deriving this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(n)$ be the number of times $*$ is performed in evaluating $T(n)$. The base case is easy enough; for any other case, we must first evaluate $f(n-2)$ 3 times (incurring $3T(n-2)$ multiplications) and then two multiplications to put everything together. Hence,

$$T(1) = 1$$

$$T(2k+1) = 3T(2k-1) + 2$$

We may solve this recurrence to get $$T(2k+1) = \frac{2}{3} 3^{k+1} - 1 $$